# Jquery find if the page contains specific id?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Is there some one can help me about this? If the page contains id = "item1"  executes #home.hide(); I am really frustrated about this.    My code:

```
<tr>
<td id = "item1">
</tr>

if($("body:has(#item1)")){
$('#home').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 11):

If what you're trying to do is to execute `$('#home').hide();` only if the `#item1` object is present, then you would do that like this:

```
if ($("#item1").length > 0) {
    $('#home').hide();
}
```

There is no need for checking if `#item1` is in `body` since that's the only place it can be.  You can simply just check for `#item1` since ids must be unique.

You could even resort to plain JS for the condition as an illustration of how simple it is:

```
if (document.getElementById("item1")) {
    $('#home').hide();
}
```

If that isn't what you're trying to do, then please clarify your question further.

Answer (score 9):

All you need is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    if($("#item1").length) {
        $('#home').hide();
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

u can check like this

```
if($('#item1').length){
    $('#home').hide();
}
```

this will return true if there is such an element as'item1'

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('#item1').length) $('#home').hide();
```

There are other ways, but that's the simplest.